# Kalman filter pre inovation

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to track LIDAR objects using Kalman filter. The problem is that the innovation has the value 0, which makes the Kalman gain be Infinity. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is a link with the Kalman equations. The values with which I initialized the measurement and process covariance matrix are listed below. The update code is also shown below. When I debug the code everything is fine until the innovation becomes 0.

```
this->lidar_R << std_laspx_, 0, 0, 0,
    0, std_laspy_, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0;

this->lidar_H << 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0;

P_ << 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1000, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1000, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1000, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1000;

 MatrixXd PHt = this->P_ * H.transpose();
 //S becomes 0
 MatrixXd S = H * PHt + R;
 //S_inv becomes INFINITY
 MatrixXd S_inv_ = S.inverse();
 MatrixXd K = PHt * S_inv_;

VectorXd y = Z - Hx;

this->x_ = this->x_ + K*y;
MatrixXd I = MatrixXd::Identity(x_.size(), x_.size());
this->P_ = (I - K * H) * this->P_;
```

Comment: This question should be migrated to: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I don't any questions here. Can you clarify what your question was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your matrix definitions, the issue is S always singular so it can never be inverted

I reimplemented the computation with numpy and here are the numbers

```
H = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

P = np.identity(5) * 1000

R = np.array([[100, 0, 0, 0], [0, 100, 0, 0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]])

S=H.dot(P.dot(np.transpose(H)))+R
```

and `S` is

```
array([[1100.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0., 1100.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])
```

Basically the definition of `H` with its all zeros lines cancels part of the information (make it unobservable) and you also do not have any observation noise component for them

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the determinant of S is zero before you do the inverse. If that is the case, use pseudo inverse.